# Use Microsoft Forms to edit an existing row in Excel online

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

It is easy to create a form to add data to a spreadsheet. In Office 365, you can start from Forms, or create a spreadsheet and select Insert → Forms → New Form.

Once the form is created and circulated, other people can access the form and add rows to the underlying spreadsheet. See, for example, https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/create-a-form-with-microsoft-forms-4ffb64cc-7d5d-402f-b82e-b1d49418fd9d?WT.mc_id=365AdminCSH

I would like my users to be able to update an existing row in a similar way. They should not have to run Excel. Is this possible?

(There is a menu item in Excel Online: Insert → Forms → Edit Form. That seems to mean edit the form structure. I can’t find a way to allow remote users to edit the spreadsheet data.)

Comment: I'm afraid not. When we insert a Form in Excel Online, it will add a new Tab called like "Form1" with a linked updatable table. The table is created according to your form and it has some fixed columns recording form pesponsers' information. There seems to be no method to create a form based on our existing table/row. We can't make our existing table/row updatable using Microsoft Forms.

Comment: @HerbGu_MSFT You should make that an answer, so the question can be closed.

Comment: I'm glad to see that my reply was helpful to your question. I will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not.

When we insert a Form in Excel Online, it will add a new Tab called like "Form1" with a linked updatable table. The table is created according to your form and it has some fixed columns recording form responders' information.

There seems to be no method to create a form based on our existing table/row. We can't make our existing table/row updatable using Microsoft Forms.